# Pyomo and GAMS Compatibility issues

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm new to Pyomo and have a bit of experience with GAMS. I want to use Pyomo with GAMS. I'm using a M1 chip Mac and using anaconda to run python with Spyder. I have installed GAMS by checking 'add to PATH'. I have pyomo installed in the base anaconda environment. When I run a pyomo model with gams with the following code:

```
solver = SolverFactory('gams:ipopt')
solver.solve(model, tee=1)
```

But get the error:

NameError: No 'gams' command found on system PATH - GAMS shell solver functionality is not available.

I have GAMS v43 and Python 3.10.8.

- I checked that GAMS executable file is accessible from the terminal py running 'gams'.
- I have tried checking the location of GAMS and it is included in the PATH.
- I added the GAMS location using Spyder's Python path manager.
- I added the GAMS location inside the code with `os.environ['PATH'].`
- I used

```
 solver = SolverFactory('gams:ipopt', solver_io='gams', add_options=['sysDir=/Library/Frameworks/GAMS.framework/Versions/43/Resources'])
```

I'm not very knowledgeable with these kind of stuff so I may have done redundant or useless stuff. I know there are other solvers but I need to use GAMS specifically. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem (I'm just trying to use a different GAMS solver).
For some reason, the PATH environment variable for my conda environment is not the same as the system PATH. Therefore, the GAMS directory was not in my conda environment's PATH environment variable. You can verify if this is happening to you by importing the os module calling

```
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

If you don't see the GAMS directory (something like C:\GAMS\41), then you can add it to the conda environment's PATH variable by doing the following.

1. Navigate to <your_anaconda_folder>/envs/<your_conda_env>/etc/conda
2. Create a file called env_vars.bat (if you're on Windows) or env_vars.sh (otherwise)
3. In that file write

   @echo off

   set PATH=%PATH%;\path\to\GAMS\directory

if you're on Windows or

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/GAMS/directory
```

otherwise.

4. Deactivate and then reactivate your conda env (from now on, every time you activate your conda env, it will call this script to add the GAMS directory to the environment PATH variable).
5. Run your Pyomo script and it should now be able to see the gams solver.

One thing to watch out for however is this. I was using VS Code to run my Python scripts, I wonder if Spyder works the same way. VS Code doesn't actually activate the conda environment when it runs a Python script. You can see this by the fact that when it runs a python script, you'll see

```
/path/to/conda/env/python.exe /full/path/to/script.py
```

instead of

```
python script.py
```

Thus, when I try to run the Python script in VS Code, it does not load the GAMS directory into the PATH environment variable and therefore I get the same error you've shown above. However, when I open up an anaconda prompt (Windows) or terminal (Otherwise), activate the conda environment, and run the Python script from there, it works fine.